# how to plot saved file without frozen window

Tags: python, plot, wxmpl

I'm trying to read txt file and plot it by pressing button. While everything seems going OK, i can not press any button to stop or do different thing because of having frozen window.

The minimal example of code:

```
from wxmplot import PlotPanel

def save_f( self, event ):
    obj = event.GetEventObject()
    isPressed = obj.GetValue()  
    if isPressed:
        f2 = open("C:\\Users\\GCS-User\\Desktop\\16dk.txt","r")            
        #while 1:
        try:
            for line in f2:    #store
                data = line.split(",")     
                if data[0] == "b'$GNVTG":          
                    velocity = data[7]
                    vel = float(velocity)
                    y2.append(vel/3.6) 

                if data[0] == "b'$GNGGA":

                    altitude=data[9]
                    print(altitude)
                    timm=data[1]
                    tim=float(timm)
                    tim=tim+30000

                    hour = tim//10000
                    minute = (tim//100)%100
                    second = tim%100
                    zaman = hour*3600 + minute*60 + second                        
                    altitude=float(altitude)
                    x1.append(zaman)
                    y1.append(altitude)                   
                    self.plotpanel.plot(x1, y1)                 
        finally:
            f2.close()
    else: 
        self.Destroy()
```

I'm using **wxmplot** library for plotting. However **matplotlib** library gave same problem. Am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How big is your txt file?

Comment: nearly 20 000 line(when i used matplotlib it wait till whole file have read then plot(it last 2-3 min then plot)). But in wxmplot it read and plot simultaneously but freeze

Comment: If it freezes when it is reading the file and then plots and becomes normal, then it is because you are plotting on your GUI Thread, which freezes the GUI itself. I would recommend checking out threading and run the plotting in a different thread. I personally have not worked with wxmplot but it should matplotlib for sure

Comment: Actually i dont use any thread or wxTimer for plotting stored data. Should i use? **My expected** is when  i pressed the button(read from .txt file and plot), all of the data has to plot immediately. By the way, i created this file from serial port which read 10 sentence per second and my data is nealy 15 min recorded of serial port